# AWS CloudWatch Schedule + Lambda: trigger not working

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I have set up a simple Lambda function to print out a line of text on execution with a java jar file. I can run the a test with the "Test" button fine. I also have set up a 5 min CloudWatch Schedule trigger, schedule expression: rate(5 minutes). The trigger is enabled. I can view the trigger and confirm in "Edit"  the trigger is assigned to my function and also that it will use a static JSON as input. For some reason my function doesn't seem to be getting triggered with my 5-min trigger - I'm expecting to see some logs for the trigger, but there is nothing at all. I'm using this logger: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger. I wonder if there is another setting I'm not aware of that needs to be set to get the trigger working. Thank you for your time.

## 1 Edit: resolution

The timer is for lambda to http into ElasticSearch service. Our ElasticSearch service became none-responsive and we had to recreate it. After we recreated the ElasticSearch service, the timer started working... Although the timer works, in console, I started seeing dupes of my timer. After I turned teh timer off, it created yet another duplicate of it self. Seems like a buggy UI. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Just to rule out an issue with the logger -- if you go the the Lambda Management Console and click on the "Monitoring" tab -- do you see any invocations or errors?

Comment: @DaveMaple: Hello, under "Monitoring" I see the graphs, and also this message "This function contains external libraries. Uploading a new file will override these libraries."  ,  but no errors.

Comment: do you see invocations in the graph every 5 minutes?

Comment: @DaveMaple: Not every 5 minutes, I can only tell that there was a spike for invocation, and a spike in duration, but I think that's for my initial test only. I refreshed since, and the graphs are not changing.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this issue in the past, and there may be another way to fix this, but how I did it was I specified a role-arn to the created Rule (the CloudWatch trigger) that has the ability to invoke a lambda function.  The policy document I used is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I cannot figure out how to do this via the Console/Web Interface.  But you can do it via the [AWS Command Line Interface - Rule - Put Rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/put-rule.html).  So you would need to:

1. Create a Policy with the Above document
2. Create a Role for your CloudWatch Rule
3. Attach the policy you created in step 1 to the role create in step 2
4. Create your CloudWatch Rule as you did before but use the given Role.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the recommendation. The timer started working on its own after we recreated one of the services in play, please see the above description. But thank you nonetheless, I will keep your post in mind and might still need to use it once we figure out permissions for everything we have in aws.

Comment: That policy document is identical to the AWS-managed 'AWSLambdaRole' policy - so in step 3, you could just attach that 'AWSLambdaRole' (and skip step 1).

Answer (score 0):

If its the case that you are doing is via java sdk, here is the solution after you put lambda as a target to CW.

AddPermissionRequest addPermissionRequest = new AddPermissionRequest();
        addPermissionRequest.setStatementId("12345ff");  //A unique means of identification of your permission
        addPermissionRequest.withSourceArn(ruleArn);
        addPermissionRequest.setAction("lambda:InvokeFunction");
        addPermissionRequest.setPrincipal("events.amazonaws.com");
        addPermissionRequest.setFunctionName("your lambda's name here");

```
    AWSLambdaAsyncClient lambdaClient = new AWSLambdaAsyncClient();
    lambdaClient.withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1); //specify whichever region your lambda is hosted in
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//*Build client* 
AmazonCloudWatchEvents cwe =
                AmazonCloudWatchEventsClientBuilder.defaultClient();

            //*Add rules*
                PutRuleRequest rulerequest = new PutRuleRequest()
                    .withName(name).withRoleArn(your-role-arn)
                    .withScheduleExpression(yourExpiryByRateorCron)
                    .withState(RuleState.ENABLED);

                PutRuleResult ruleresponse = cwe.putRule(rulerequest);

                //*Add targets*

                    Target target = new Target()
                        .withArn(lambda-arn)
                        .withId(id).withInput(input);

                    PutTargetsRequest targetrequest = new PutTargetsRequest()
                        .withTargets(target)
                        .withRule(rule-name);

                    cwe.putTargets(targetrequest);

                    AWSLambda al = AWSLambdaAsyncClientBuilder.defaultClient();
          // *Add Permissions*              
                    AddPermissionRequest apr = new AddPermissionRequest()
                            .withFunctionName("function:yourfunctionname")
                            .withAction("lambda:InvokeFunction")
                            .withPrincipal("events.amazonaws.com")
                            .withStatementId(id)
                            .withSourceArn(arn);
                            al.addPermission(apr);
```